# Mostrar la información de un marcador de Google Maps sin necesidad de dar clic en android?

Tags: android, google-maps

Es posible mostrar la informacion de mis marcadores sin necesidad de dar clic? actualmente tengo una vista donde muestro unos marcadores pero tengo que dar clic para ver el `title` definido, quisiera que el usuario al mostrarseles los marcadores ya vaya con el title:
Este es mi codigo para generar los marcadores:

```
for (Colaborador c: lista){
            String id=String.valueOf(c.getId());
            Marker marker=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(c.getPlColvol().getLatitud()), Double.parseDouble(c.getPlColvol().getLongitud())))
                    .title(c.getPlColvol().getNombre()+"--"+c.getClave().getClave())
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.gota_sangre)));
            marker.setTag(c);
            //marker.showInfoWindow();
            misMarkers.add(marker);
        }
```

Comment: ¿Deseas que en la imagen del Marcador se muestre también un titulo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el método [title()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker)

> [title()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker) : Una cadena que se muestra en la ventana de información
>   cuando el usuario toca el marcador.

ejemplo:

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
    .title("Posición Igmer")).showInfoWindow();
```

Sin embargo este titulo únicamente se mostraría en la ventana al dar clic al elemento, no lo llamaría una "limitación" ya que tu ves el mapa y este tiene sus propias descripciones.

Sin embargo si deseas un texto a un lado del marcador puedes usar esta opción:

[**Android Google Maps Floating Marker Titles**](https://github.com/androidseb/android-google-maps-floating-marker-titles)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias!! me ha servido mucho

Comment: Excelente @IgmerRodriguez ! un saludo!